# Directive not updating controller property

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have written a custom directive to detect the enter key being pressed inside a text box. Here is the directive code

```
import { BookmarkService } from "../services/bookmarkService";
import { qlik, QlikBookmarkInfo } from "../qlikInit";

class BookmarkListController {
/**
 * Injection parameters
 */
public static $inject: string[] = ["$scope", "bookmarkSvc"];

private $scope: ng.IScope;
private bookmarkSvc: BookmarkService;
private bookmark: QlikBookmarkInfo;
private bookmarkIndex: number;
private showToolbar: boolean = false;
public showAddTextbox: boolean = false;
public newBookmarkTitle: string = "";
private showEditBookmark: boolean = false;

public constructor(scope: ng.IScope, bookmarkSvc: BookmarkService) {
    this.$scope = scope;
    this.bookmarkSvc = bookmarkSvc;
}

public applyBookmark(bookmarkId: string, bookmarkTitle: string, bookmarkDescription: string): void {
    this.bookmark = {Id: "", Title: "", Description: ""};
    this.bookmark.Id = bookmarkId;
    this.bookmark.Title = bookmarkTitle;
    this.bookmark.Description = bookmarkDescription;
    this.showToolbar = true;
    qlik.applyBookmark("ABC", bookmarkId);
}

public createBookmark(): void {
    this.showAddTextbox = true;
}

public removeBookmark(): void {
    qlik.removeBookmark("ABC", this.bookmark.Id);
    this.bookmarkIndex = this.bookmarkSvc.bookmarksInfo.indexOf(this.bookmark);
    this.bookmarkSvc.bookmarksInfo.splice(this.bookmarkIndex, 1);
    this.showToolbar = false;
}

public editBookmark(): void {
    this.showEditBookmark = true;
    // do something
}

/* tslint:disable:no-any */
public saveBookmark(e: any): void {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        qlik.createBookmark("ABC", this.newBookmarkTitle);
        this.showAddTextbox = false;
        this.newBookmarkTitle = "";
    }
}
/* tslint:enable:no-any */
}

export class BookmarkListComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
public templateUrl: string = "bookmarkList.html";
public controller: Function = BookmarkListController;
}

export function bookmarkEnter(): ng.IDirective {
return<ng.IDirective>{
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        showAddTextbox: "=?",
        newBookmarkTitle: "=?"
    },
    link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: BookmarkListController): void => {
        element.on("keyup", (e: any): void => {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                qlik.createBookmark("ABC", controller.newBookmarkTitle);
                scope.$apply((): void => {
                    controller.showAddTextbox = false;
                    controller.newBookmarkTitle = "";
                });
            }
        });
    },
    controller: BookmarkListController,
    controllerAs: "$ctrlblc",
    bindToController: true
};
}
```

And I am using the directive as below in a bookmarkList.html file

```
<div class="dsh-ListTitle">
<h4 class="dsh-ListTitle-title">Bookmarks</h4>
<a class="dsh-List-item" ng-click="$ctrl.createBookmark()">
    <ers-icon name="add" ers-tooltip="Add Bookmark"></ers-icon>
</a>
</div>
<div class="u-flex dsh-List dsh-List-icon" ng-show="$ctrl.showToolbar">
<a class="dsh-List-item" ng-click="$ctrl.editBookmark()">
    <ers-icon name="edit" ers-tooltip="Edit Bookmark"></ers-icon>
</a>
<a class="dsh-List-item" ng-click="$ctrl.removeBookmark()">
    <ers-icon name="delete" ers-tooltip="Delete Bookmark"></ers-icon>
</a>    
</div>
<ul class="dsh-List">
<li class="dsh-List-item" ng-repeat="bookmark in $ctrl.bookmarkSvc.bookmarksInfo">
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.applyBookmark(bookmark.Id, bookmark.Title, bookmark.Description)">{{bookmark.Title}}</a>
</li>
<li class="dsh-List-item" ng-show="$ctrl.showAddTextbox">
    <input type="text" bookmark-enter showAddTextbox="$ctrl.showAddTextbox" newBookmarkTitle="$ctrl.newBookmarkTitle" ng-show="$ctrl.showAddTextbox"/>        
</li>
</ul>
```

I think I have wired up everything correctly. On the `qlik.createBookmark()` line, the `controller.newBookmarkTitle` does not have the text entered in the text box. It is coming in as an empty string. If I evaluate `element.val()`, that is having the text entered in the text box.

What am I missing here? AngularJS version 1.5 is being used.

Comment: Where is the controller code?

Comment: how do you expect to bind the text to the controller? you are binding non angular attribute to the controller.newBookmarkTitle. try replacing newBookmarkTitle="$ctrl.newBookmarkTitle" with this  ng-model="$ctrl.newBookmarkTitle"

Comment: I have tried that too, that also returns an empty string. Basically whatever value is initially set in the typescript class is what is being read in the directive. Changes made in the UI are not being reflected.

Comment: one more thing, i see you are using controllerAs $ctrlblc while $ctrl in binding. shouldnt these be the same value?

Comment: I have corrected that too and the result is still the same.

Comment: could you upload it to jsFiddle or Plunkr?it would be much easier to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You main error is in the name of attributes that are you passing the directive. 
 To be clear, if you have `scope: {showAddTextbox: '=?'}` (**camelCase**) you have to pass the attr in the html like `<input bookmark-enter show-add-textbox="$ctrl.showAddTextbox"` (**kebab-case**).
Also change `controller.` for `scope.` in your link function when you are referring to your directives parameters.

** *As an advice, instead of use `$scope.apply()` you can use `$scope.applyAsync()` or `$timeout(function(){ //your code })`. This is in case you get `$digest already in progress` angularjs error.*

EXAMPLE:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" bookmark-enter show-add-textbox="$ctrl.showAddTextbox" ng-model="$ctrl.newBookmarkTitle" ng-show="$ctrl.showAddTextbox"/>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
restrict: "A",
scope: {
    showAddTextbox: "=?",
    newBookmarkTitle: "=ngModel"
},
link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, controller: BookmarkListController): void => {
    element.on("keyup", (e: any): void => {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            qlik.createBookmark("ABC", scope.newBookmarkTitle);
            scope.$timeout(() => {
                scope.showAddTextbox = false;
                scope.newBookmarkTitle = "";
            });
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: That partially fixed the issue. The showAddTextbox field is now getting the updated value. The newBookmarkTitle value is still coming in as an empty string after it has been updated to kebab-case (didnt know such term existed until now).

`<input type="text" bookmark-enter show-add-textbox="$ctrl.showAddTextbox" new-bookmark-title="$ctrl.newBookmarkTitle" ng-show="$ctrl.showAddTextbox"/>`

Any thoughts? The only update I did in my code was for the kebab case. I did not make the other changes suggested.

Comment: Hi @sanchin... I think that is empty string because your aren't setting any value to this variable (at least seeing you controller code). But do you want that newBookmarkTitle has the text entered by the user? Maybe you use it as `ng-model` of the input instead of directive parameter.

Comment: Yes, I added the ng-model attribute and I am getting the value from the UI. Thank you!